# Alternar cores do header, com base no hover do menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um header tradicional, com logo e menu de links, gostaria de alternar as cores do header com base no hover de cada link no menu.

```css
h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff
}

header {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header-content {
    background: grey;
    padding: 30px;
}

.nav {
    background: #333;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav ul {
    float: left;
}

.nav ul,
.nav ul li {
    line-height: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 30px;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #AAA
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="header-content">
  <h1 class="logo">Header Colorido on Hover</h1>
 </div>
<nav class="nav">
 <ul>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-1"><a href="#">Header Cinza</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">Verde</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-3"><a href="#">Azul</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-4"><a href="#">Vermelho</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-5"><a href="#">Gold</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-6"><a href="#">Lime</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

**EDIT**

Desde cedo, estou pesquisando isso, encontrei uma coisa interessante, que fiquei de boca aberta, dado a sua simplicidade. Funciona, mas não como o esperado, não com toda a estrutura do html, não funciona se os links estiverem dentro de outro elemento, div, nav, header...

codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/RyEOWB

Comment: Fala John essa opção com o seletor ~ foi a primeira coisa que pensei rss, mas com o menu usando ul>li vc não vai conseguir usar esse seletor. Fiz uma opção só com css tb, mas um pouco diferente, a explicação detalhada está na minha resposta. []'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John consegui uma forma de fazer apenas com CSS sem precisar mexer na estrutura do HTML, na verdade nem encostei no HTML para colocar outra classe nem nada.

A técnica não usa o seletor adjacente **~** pois com o menu estruturado em `ul>li` não daria certo. Então eu fiz usando pseudo elemento `::after` e coloquei um `.nav ul li:nth-child(1)` para selecionar as cores no hover. *Um detalhe é que eu precisei retira `position:relative` de alguns elementos, mas isso não afetou o layout como vc pode ver*

Veja no exemplo abaixo que vc vai entender melhor.

```css
h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff
}

header {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
header::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: gray;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -2;
}

.header-content {
    /* background: gray; */
    padding: 30px;
}

.nav {
    background: #333;
    height: 60px;
    /* position: relative; */
}

.nav ul {
    float: left;
}

.nav ul,
.nav ul li {
    line-height: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* position: relative; */
    vertical-align: top;
}
/* cores no hover */
.nav ul li:hover::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: 1s;
}
.nav ul li#menu-item-1:hover::after {
    background: gray;
}
.nav ul li#menu-item-2:hover::after {
    background: green;
}
.nav ul li#menu-item-3:hover::after {
    background: blue;
}
.nav ul li#menu-item-4:hover::after {
    background: red;
}
.nav ul li#menu-item-5:hover::after {
    background: gold;
}
.nav ul li#menu-item-6:hover::after {
    background: lime;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 30px;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #AAA
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="header-content">
        <h1 class="logo">Header Colorido on Hover</h1>
    </div>
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-1"><a href="#">Header Cinza</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-2"><a href="#">Verde</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-3"><a href="#">Azul</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-4"><a href="#">Vermelho</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-5"><a href="#">Gold</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-6"><a href="#">Lime</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Simplesmente Perfeito. Eu irei utiliza-los com IDS, é mais conveniente, já que é pra um tema wordpress. Funciona como o esperado. Thx.

Comment: Que bom que te serviu @JohnQuimera já até aceitei a edição para ficar como referencia caso vc precisa dele novamente aqui.

Comment: hugocsl, seria possível manter o mesmo efeito, também com **:focus**?

Comment: @JohnQuimera vc quer manter a cor depois que clicar né? Acho que com o focus funcionaria no mobile talvez, no desktop testei aqui e não funcionou. Com target tb não vai dar pq está no elemento after... Infelizmente esse modelo com CSS acredito só funcionar dessa forma. Mas se vc vai ter esse menu em páginas diferentes, tipo em a.html, b.html, vc pode criar uma classe .active e deixar a cor marcado. Tipo `.nav ul li#menu-item-3.active::after { }` ai na página do item3 a cor fica verde entende

Comment: Exato, compreendo. Sabe, será que algo como o **superfish** funcionária? Estou tentando implementar o **js-track-focus**
aqui, ele é quase semelhante ao superfish, mais leve eu acho.

Comment: @JohnQuimera acho que nessa não consigo te ajudar, não conheço esse plugins :/

Comment: Compreendo. Geralmente quando temos um menu normal com submenu, e focamos nele com o botão esquerdo do mouse, ele fecha certo? esse **js-track-focus** evita que isso ocorra. Eu estou tentando aplica-lo ao seu código, não estou conseguindo por algum motivo. Veja uma demo desse plugin: https://codepen.io/vmitsaras/pen/ozOdYm

Comment: @JohnQuimera entendi o que vc quer, em ultimo caso acho que com "preventDefault()" e "setTimeout()" vc consegue fazer algo bem parecido sem precisar de plugin. Eu não manjo nada de JS e praticamente nada de jQuery, mas no momento te aconselho a abrir outra pergunta se é exatamente isso que vc quer. Ai alguém com mais experiencia que eu nessa área vai poder te ajudar ;)

Comment: Obrigado, eu farei isso. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Comentei no código JS o que cada comando faz para te ajudar a entender e no CSS movi a instrução `background-color` para o `header`. Assim, todo o header (exceto o que estiver definindo cor "por cima" dele, como acontece com a barra de links) receberá a nova cor.

Além disso, criei classes CSS que definirão as novas cores. Veja se é isso que precisa e qualquer dúvida, posso tentar te ajudar.

```js
var $header = $("header");
var colors = ["verde", "azul", "vermelho", "etc"];

function removeCores() {
  $.each(colors, function(i, colr) {  // Para cada cor no vetor 'colors'
      $header.removeClass(colr);  // Remove a classe do header, se houver
   });
   
}

$("header li").on("mouseleave", removeCores);

$("header li").on("mouseover", function() {
   var color = $(this).attr("data-color"); // Coleta valor do atributo 'data-color'
   
   removeCores();

   if (color == "cinza") // se for cinza, sai da funcao (pois já está definida por padrão no css.
     return;
     
   $header.addClass(color); // Adiciona a classe ao header 
});
```

```css
h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff
}

header {
    background: grey; /* CHANGED */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header-content {
    padding: 30px; /* CHANGED */
}

.nav {
    background: #333;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav ul {
    float: left;
}

.nav ul,
.nav ul li {
    line-height: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 30px;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #AAA
}


/* Colors classses */
.verde {
   background-color: green;
}
.azul{
   background-color: blue;
}
.vermelho {
    background-color: red
}
.etc {
    background-color: etc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <div class="header-content">
  <h1 class="logo">Header Colorido on Hover</h1>
 </div>
<nav class="nav">
 <ul>
<li data-color="cinza"><a href="#">Header Cinza</a></li>
<li data-color="verde"><a href="#">Verde</a></li>
<li data-color="azul"><a href="#">Azul</a></li>
<li data-color="vermelho"><a href="#">Vermelho</a></li>
<li data-color="etc"><a href="#">Etc</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

---

### Seleção por ID

```js
 $header = $("header");
var colors = {
    "menu-item-01" : "cinza", 
    "menu-item-02" : "verde", 
    "menu-item-03" : "azul", 
    "menu-item-04" : "vermelho", 
    "menu-item-05" : "etc"
};

function removeCores() {
    $.each(colors, function (i, colr) {  // Para cada cor no objeto 'colors'
        $header.removeClass(colr);  // Remove a classe do header, se houver
    });

}

$("header li").on("mouseleave", removeCores);

$("header li").on("mouseover", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); // Coleta valor do atributo 'id'
    var color = colors[id];      // Seleciona o nome da classe no objeto colors.

    removeCores();

    if (color == "cinza") // se for cinza, sai da funcao (pois já está definida por padrão no css.
        return;

    $header.addClass(color); // Adiciona a classe ao header 
});
```

```css
h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff
}

header {
    background: grey; /* CHANGED */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header-content {
    padding: 30px; /* CHANGED */
}

.nav {
    background: #333;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav ul {
    float: left;
}

.nav ul,
.nav ul li {
    line-height: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 30px;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #AAA
}


/* Colors classses */
.verde {
   background-color: green;
}
.azul{
   background-color: blue;
}
.vermelho {
    background-color: red
}
.etc {
    background-color: etc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="header-content">
        <h1 class="logo">Header Colorido on Hover</h1>
 </div>
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li id="menu-item-01"><a href="#">Header Cinza</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-02"><a href="#">Verde</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-03"><a href="#">Azul</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-04"><a href="#">Vermelho</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-05"><a href="#">Etc</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Wesley Gonçalves, sua solução é perfeita, mas veja, pretendo utilizar isso em um tema wordpress, portanto, seria melhor utilização de IDS em vez dos nomes das cores. `menu-item-01, menu-item-02, etc.`

Comment: Desde cedo, estou pesquisando isso, encontrei uma coisa interessante, que fiquei de boca aberta, dado a sua simplicidade. Funciona, mas não como o esperado, não com toda a estrutura do html, não funciona se os links estiver dentro de outro elemento. veja: https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/RyEOWB

Comment: Obrigado, @John Quimera. De fato seu exemplo do codepen não funciona porque ele usa seletor de próximo elemento `~`. 
Atualizei a resposta selecionando o item da barra de navegação pelo id, veja se é isso de que precisa. No jQuery, ao invés de um array, eu usei um objeto que relaciona o ID do item com a classe CSS que será adicionada ao `header`.

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o método `.hover` do jQuery. A 1ª função é o evento `mouseenter` e a 2ª o `mouseleave`. Aí você envia a cor como parâmetro para uma outra função que irá alterar a cor de fundo do elemento.

Então você pega o índice do elemento e usa esse valor em um `switch` para escolher a respectiva cor.

**Veja:**

```js
$(function(){
   function C(c){
      $(".header-content")
      .css("background-color", c);
   }
   
   $(".nav ul li").hover(
      function(){
         var idx = $(this).index(); // pego o índice do elemento
         var cor;
   
         switch(idx){
            case 0: // cinza
               cor = "gray";
               break;
            case 1: // verde
               cor = "green";
               break;
            case 2: // azul
               cor = "blue";
               break;
            case 3: // vermelho
               cor = "red";
               break;
            case 4: // etc
               cor = "lime";
               break;
         }
   
         C(cor);
      },
      function(){
         C("gray");
      }
   );
});
```

```css
h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff
}

header {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header-content {
    background: grey;
    padding: 30px;
}

.nav {
    background: #333;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav ul {
    float: left;
}

.nav ul,
.nav ul li {
    line-height: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 30px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <div class="header-content">
  <h1 class="logo">Header Colorido on Hover</h1>
 </div>
   <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Header Cinza</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Verde</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Azul</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Vermelho</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Etc</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: muito bom, pretendo utilizar isso em um tema wordpress, portanto, seria melhor utilização de IDS em vez dos nomes das cores no codigo. ´menu-item-01, menu-item-02, etc. ´

Comment: Eu não usei nomes de cores, usei o index das LIs

Comment: tipo assim: https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/RyEOWB só que isso não funciona dentro dos elementos, alias eu fiquei realmente impressionado por essa solução simples apenas com css, funciona até no IE7. Como isso é possível?

Comment: Com essa estrutura do codepen é fácil só com CSS porque as LIs são irmãs da div `main-header`... neste caso aqui não tem como selecionar um pai a partir de filhos com CSS

Answer (score -1):

Atribuindo um id para cada cor:

```
<li id="Cinza"><a href="#">Header Cinza</a></li>
<li id="Verde"><a href="#">Verde</a></li>
<li id="Azul"><a href="#">Azul</a></li>
<li id="Vermelho"><a href="#">Vermelho</a></li>
<li id="Etc"><a href="#">Etc</a></li>
```

No `css`basta usar os ids para resolver o problema:

```
#Cinza:hover{background-color:grey}
#Verde:hover{background-color:green}
#Azul:hover{background-color:blue}
#Vermelho:hover{background-color:red}
#Etc:hover{background-color:etc}
```

No `Jquery`, aqui vc muda a cor:

```
$('li').on('mouseover',function(){
    var cor = $(this).attr('id');
    $('header').css('background-color',cor);
});
```

Aqui volta para cor padrão:

```
$('header').on('mouseleave',function(){
    $('header').css('background-color','COR PADRÃO');//onde vc coloca a cor padrão do menu
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas não é isso. O hover do menu deve ser apenas a deixa para alternar a cor do Header! é no header que a mágica deve acontecer. Quero um efeito semelhante ao tecmundo.

Comment: Editei ai a resposta com uma possibilidade